# Registering new custom ComputedItem to ComputedItemTypesRegistry

Tags: intershop

By following the Cookbook - Basket Calculation (https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/23V395)

I have created two new custom computed items with unique jaxb name:

[image: custom ComputedItems]

---

Also both of this computed items are registered in ComputedItemTypeRegistry in custom class which extends Cartridge class:

[image: custom Cartridge class]

---

And now when the calculation is called and new calculation rule is executed i am getting an exception that first computed item MKComputedBenefitItemImpl is not registered:

[image: exception]

Answer (score 0):

New cartridge class A1MKCartridge wasn't recognized due to wrong location of cartridge properties.

---

Guide - 7.10 Migration of Cartridge Properties:

https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/28Z691

The `<cartridge_name>.properties` were moved from \share\system\config\cartridges to `<cartridge_name>\src\main\resources\cartridges` in ICM 7.10. This has the following implications.